# How to make recycling in Combination with repetition Problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am wondering how to make recycling in Combination with repetition problem.

1. Problem

John has **'n'** cookies, and he want to eat them in **'d'** days.
But, John want to eat them under **'x'**. What is the whole possiblity in mathematical expression?
For example, if $n=5, d=2, x=5$, The possibility is below,

$$(day_1, day_2)$$
$$(1, 4)$$
$$(4, 1)$$
$$(2, 3)$$
$$(3, 2)$$

$(5,0)$and$(0,5)$ is excepted in this way.

2. My attempts

I made a combination with repetition in this problem.
$${}_{n+1}H_{d-1}-\sum_{i=x}^n ?$$

So, I took whole possiblity by using combination with repetition.
In above example, the whole possibility is
${}_{5+1}H_{2-1}={}_{6}H_{1}={}_{6+1-1}C_{1}={}_{6}C_{1}$=6

But i didn't get an idea for filling with '?' as mathematical expression.

Can I get some help?

Comment: Can you define $x$?

Comment: This is not clear.  We don't know the "eating rules" so we don't know what choices John can make.

Comment: I am sorry for my instruction, I will correct quickly!

Comment: 'x' means the limited number of cookies in this way

Comment: This is not at all clear.  Are you asking for the number of $d-$tuples of positive integers that sum to $x$?  If so, that is given by [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: I want to get '?' in mathematical expression, In this problem, the whole possibility is limited in 'x', so, I didn't expand Stars and Bars in this problem.

Comment: Ok, well I for one don't understand what you are asking.  Perhaps someone else does.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

@J.Lee, I'm not 100% sure I understand your question correctly. So I'm going to write my understanding of the question, and then sketch a solution. If I understood the question incorrectly, please correct me.

**Question:** John has $n$ cookies to eat in $d$ days. On each day he will eat a whole number of cookies. How many ways can he divide the cookies between the days, given the constraint that on no single day will he eat $x$ or more cookies?

**Solution:**

The maximum number of cookies the constraint allows is $d(x-1)$, so if $d(x-1) < n$, i.e., if $x < 1 + \frac{n}{d}$, there is no solution. We therefore consider $x \geq 1 + \frac{n}{d}$.

We'll start the way you started (I think -- I'm not sure what your $H$ refers to). The total number of ways to eat $n$ cookies in $d$ days is $\binom{n+d-1}{d-1}$, by the well-known "stars and bars" argument.

Now we subtract the number of possibilities that involve eating $x$ or more cookies on a single day. If $x > n$, there are no such possibilities, so we have our final answer. Otherwise, we count the number of possibilities by choosing a day ($\binom{d}{1}$ choices), placing $x$ cookies on that day, and dividing the rest of the cookies among all the days (including the chosen day, since it may receive more than $x$ cookies) according to "stars and bars" ($\binom{n-x+d-1}{d-1}$ choices). So in this case our solution (tentatively) is $\binom{n+d-1}{d-1} - \binom{d}{1}\binom{n-x+d-1}{d-1}$.

Now if $2x > n$ (i.e., $x > \frac{n}{2}$), this is the final solution, but otherwise we have overcounted situations in which at least $x$ cookies are eaten on $2$ different days, and we have to add them back. According to the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, continuing this argument will give a final solution of

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{x}\right\rfloor} (-1)^i \binom{d}{i} \binom{n-ix+d-1}{d-1}
$$

Comment: Really I wanted it. But my expression is not at all clear. So sorry for that instruction and thanks to the solution.!!!!!